# Uncaught TypeError: this._platformLocation.onPopState is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I built an angular application which runs fine if I serve it in a non-production mode but if I run it with `--prod` I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: this._platformLocation.onPopState is not a function`

The LocationStrategy is provided correctly and it's the latest angular version which should have this bug fixed already.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "~11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "~4.0.0",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "2.2.7",
    "core-js": "~2.5.7",
    "is-docker": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.2",
    "lit-html": "~1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "split.js": "~1.5.9",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.9",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~0.2.2",
    "karma-detect-browsers": "~2.3.3",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
```

Can somebody explain why this error happens? And why it only pops up in the production build?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: The problem was that some webcomponents I used had older ECMAScript versions than the angular application. Resolving that issue fixed the problem.